# Bootstrap Table - Send request to server for variables that the user can see in the view (visible records)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I am using the Bootstrap table and I have data-pagination="true". I also update my table by clicking on the update link and my server-side gather the updated values and send it to the Client to show. Lets assume that I have 48 rows so I have 5 pages. What I would like to do is to only send variables (on the portion of the table -e.g, 1st page with 10 rows- that the user can see - Visible records) to the server not all variables on all rows (48 of them). What should I do?

HTML:

```
<td class = "resvpt">{{ valpt[count] }}</td>
```

Java Script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#retrieve').bind('click', function() {
        //console.log($SCRIPT_ROOT);
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/scf', function(data) {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("resvpt");
            var i;
            for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
                y[i].innerHTML = data.valpt[i];
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'getData' method will get the loaded data of table at the moment that this method is called. If you set the useCurrentPage to true the method will return the data in the current page.

```
var objectInfo = [];    
objectInfo = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData', 'useCurrentPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only load the visible records. When the user moves to the next page, use AJAX to fetch those records.

This will require implementing **PageSize** and **PageNumber** filters serverside.

The [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin can make this very easy and can leverage bootstrap as well.

Comment: I edited my question, I misspoke last time.  I am loading the visible records, what I would like to do is to ask for the visible records not all.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's where the PageSize and PageNumber filters will come into play on the server